# iOs CoreBluetooth Central Server and Peripheral Client

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

Currently, iOS does not support the combination GAP Central role and ATT Server role as well as the combination GAP Peripheral role and ATT Client role.

Is Apple working on this? Does someone know when it will be possible to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you develop a non iOS peripheral, then you should be able to start acting as ATT client once the iOS central connected to you. The ATT database is shared accross applications and should be accessible this way. You can initialize it in a separate app or in the same app using a CPBeripheralManager.

Otherwise, there has been no indication from Apple that they would be considering this use case so I wouldn't expect it be implemented in the foreseeable future.

Comment: If it is so, I would be very much interested by an example code of such an application. I had searched a lot on the Internet and had not found such a possibility but your suggestion is worth looking into it !

Comment: There is no example code that I know of. There's been a thread on the bluetooth-dev mailing list where Sergey has explained this solution http://lists.apple.com/archives/bluetooth-dev/2013/Nov/msg00047.html Later on someone reported that they were using this option on an nFRF8000 based peripheral because that stack supports only the peripheral role.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I learned a lot of things reading the thread from your link. It is too bad Apple did not document this clearly and do not give examples. Indeed, a device which needs to have a reduced power consumption cannot allow itself to be the initiator of the connection. But if this device is using the iPhone information, it would be in the Bluetooth SIG spirit for the device to be an ATT Client.