# iOS - Making a remote Bluetooth LE device subscribe to Characteristic changes

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

I am trying to rebuild an Android BLE App in iOS where the BLE Central is working as both Client and Server.
At first the local device is scanning for a BLE device, discovers it and connects to it. (Client role) Then the local device takes over the Server Role and notifies the BLE device if any Characteristic values are changed.

In Android it works fine because I can use the discovered BluetoothDevice and via the `BluetoothDevice.connectGatt` method make it subscribe to my characteristic changes. When changing the value I use the `notifyCharacteristicChanged` method to notify the device.

I guess the most important difference is that in iOS after device discovery, I only get a `CBPeripheral` as a discovered device, which I cannot use for any Client-based functions such as subscribing to a Server. At least, that's what I couldn't figure out so far.

I read this: [iOs CoreBluetooth Central Server and Peripheral Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655068/ios-corebluetooth-central-server-and-peripheral-client) thread and the linked mailing list discussion: http://lists.apple.com/archives/bluetooth-dev/2013/Nov/msg00047.html about iOS devices acting as Client and Servers and theoretically it should be possible and I was wondering if someone found a way to make a discovered remote device subscribe to my Characteristic changes.

Comment: Is your remote device also iOS-based? Getting from CBPeripheral to CBCentral is hard to achieve with the current Core Bluetooth API.

Comment: No, the remote is not iOS-based. It's just a BLE chip being programmed as a peripheral with client role for some services.

Comment: In this case, you should also start a CBPeripheralManager, and then use your BLE chip to discover the characteristics within that CBPeripheralManager. Then you will get a CBCentral that you can use to notify characteristic value changes.

Comment: The problem is that the chip is not able to discover anything itself, because it's only made to act as the peripheral and can only advertise and react to notifications. Everything else needs to be done within the iPhone application as it seems.